# Gray out image with CSS?

Tags: css

What's the best way (if any) to make an image appear "grayed out" with CSS (i.e., without loading a separate, grayed out version of the image)?

My context is that I have rows in a table that all have buttons in the right most cell and some rows need to look lighter than others. So I can make the font lighter easily of course but I'd also like to make the images lighter without having to manage two versions of each image.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Does it have to be gray? You could just set the opacity of the image lower (to dull it). Alternatively, you could create a `<div>` overlay and set that to be gray (change the alpha to get the effect).

- html:

  ```
  <div id="wrapper">
      <img id="myImage" src="something.jpg" />
  </div>
  ```
- css:

  ```css
  #myImage {
      opacity: 0.4;
      filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
  }

  /* or */

  #wrapper {
      opacity: 0.4;
      filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
      background-color: #000;
  }
  ```

Comment: Good ol' internet explorer. You can do more with the filter attribute; as it uses DirectDraw to do the rendering. But, then it only works on IE

Comment: i had to do using jQuery.. i did $("#imgid").filter.opacity = "0.3"

Answer (score 223):

Use the CSS3 filter property:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
         -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

The browser support is pretty decent, https://caniuse.com/css-filters.

Comment: to make it even darker, add `contrast(x%)` property, e.g. `grayscale(100%) contrast(30%)`.

Comment: Browser support is a real issue as it definitely doesn't work in IE10, IE11, FF26, Safari 5.1.x (Win7 x64), or basically anything outside of Chrome (example.)

Comment: This does not allow you to set it to a light gray, but if on a white background, you can use use it in conjunction with opacity to make that happen ;
`img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity: 0.4;
}
`

Answer (score 54):

Your here:

```
<a href="#"><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
```

Css Gray:

```
img{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */}
```

Ungray:

```
a:hover img{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none ; /* IE6-9 */
    zoom:1; /* needed to trigger "hasLayout" in IE if no width or height is set */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
    }
```

I found it at: http://zkiwi.com/topic/chuyen-hinh-mau-thanh-trang-den-bang-css-nhu-the-nao

**Edit:** IE10+ does not support DX filters as IE9 and earlier have done, nor does it support a prefixed version of the greyscale filter.
You can fix it, use one in two solutions below:

1. Set IE10+ to render using IE9 standards mode using the following meta element in the head: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`
2. Use an SVG overlay in IE10 to accomplish the greyscaling [internet explorer 10 - howto apply grayscale filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter)

Comment: Thank you!  This is the only answer that helped me get this working in  Firefox!

Comment: @Jamie Carl: Glad i can help. This code work good in all Browsers :)

Comment: @ErenYeager in ungray, why zoom: 1? I guess that is a mistake?

Answer (score 26):

If you don't mind using a bit of JavaScript, jQuery's [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) works nicely in every browser I've tried.

```
jQuery(selector).fadeTo(speed, opacity);
```

Comment: Just stumbled across my old answer here again. There's no way I'd use JS for this now. Pure CSS is much better.

Answer (score 23):

Better to support all the browsers:

```
img.lessOpacity {               
   opacity: 0.4;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40);
   zoom: 1;  /* needed to trigger "hasLayout" in IE if no width or height is set */ 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## To gray out:

### “to achromatize.”

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

```css
@keyframes achromatization {
 0% {}
 25% {}
 75% {filter: grayscale(100%);}
 100% {filter: grayscale(100%);}
}

p {
 font-size: 5em;
 color: yellow;
 animation: achromatization 2s ease-out infinite alternate;
}
p:first-of-type {
 background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<p>
 ⚡ Bzzzt!
</p>
<p>
 ⚡ Bzzzt!
</p>
```

### “to fill with gray.”

```
filter: contrast(0%);
```

```css
@keyframes gray-filling {
 0% {}
 25% {}
 50% {filter: contrast(0%);}
 60% {filter: contrast(0%);}
 70% {filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%) invert(100%);}
 80% {filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%) invert(100%);}
 90% {filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%);}
 100% {filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%);}
}

p {
 font-size: 5em;
 color: yellow;
 animation: gray-filling 5s ease-out infinite alternate;
}
p:first-of-type {
 background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<p>
 ⚡ Bzzzt!
</p>
<p>
 ⚡ Bzzzt!
</p>
```

---

### Helpful notes

- [What's the difference between CSS3 filter grayscale and saturate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621307/whats-the-difference-between-css3-filter-grayscale-and-saturate)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1

Comment: contrast was what i wanted

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that let's you set the color of the background. If  you don't want to use float, then you might need to set the width and height manually. But even that  really depends on the surrounding CSS/HTML.

```
<style>
#color {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}#opacity    {
    opacity : 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); 
}
</style>

<div id="color">
  <div id="opacity">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rgba()` in css to define a color instead of `rgb()`.  Like this:
`style='background-color: rgba(128,128,128, 0.7);`

Gives you the same color as `rgb(128,128,128)` but with a 70% opacity so the stuff behind only shows thru 30%.  CSS3 but it's worked in most browsers since 2008.  Sorry, no #rrggbb syntax that I know of.  Play with the numbers - you can wash out with white, shadow out with gray, whatever you want to dilute with.

OK so you make a a rectangle in semi-transparent gray (or whatever color) and lay it on top of your image, maybe with position:absolute and a z-index higher than zero, and you put it just before your image and the default location for the rectangle will be the same upper-left corner of your image.  Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering  filter:expression is a Microsoft extension to CSS, so it will only work in Internet Explorer. If you want to grey it out, I would recommend that you set it's opacity to 50% using a bit of javascript.

http://lyxus.net/mv would be a good place to start, because it discusses an opacity
script that works with Firefox, Safari, KHTML, Internet Explorer and CSS3 capable browsers.

You might also want to give it a grey border.

Comment: opacity is a css3 feature though, the filter part is for MSIE specifically, other browsers will pick up opacity