# Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS

Tags: image, css, grayscale

Is there a simple way to display a color bitmap in grayscale with just `HTML/CSS`?

It doesn't need to be IE-compatible (and I imagine it won't be) -- if it works in FF3 and/or Sf3, that's good enough for me.

I know I can do it with both `SVG` and Canvas, but that seems like a lot of work right now.

Is there a truly lazy person's way to do this?

Comment: *"It doesn't need to be IE-compatible (and I imagine it won't be)"*?? 
IE is providing a set of [DX filters](http://bit.ly/j8TnAG) **since 1997** (IE4) which does this job with mere CSS and lot more. Now they have [dropped DX filters in IE10](http://bit.ly/rVt1aH) and are strictly following the standard SVG based filters. You might want to take a look at [this](http://bit.ly/oFcgbl) and [this demo](http://bit.ly/oSYpAe).

Comment: @vulcanraven It's not really 'mere CSS' - if you disable active scripting in IE the filters stop working.

Comment: @robertc, thats about right. In contrast, if you disable javascript in any browser almost every RIA including Stackoverflow will stop working (unless the web developer have implemented the HTML-only version fallback).

Comment: Just use the CSS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286275/gray-out-image-with-css/13909292#13909292
Get my answer in this question

Answer (score 798):

[Support for CSS filters has landed in Webkit.](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit)  So we now have a cross-browser solution.

```css
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
}

/* Disable grayscale on hover */
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Wikimedia_Canadian_Community_Logo.svg/240px-Wikimedia_Canadian_Community_Logo.svg.png">
```

---

**What about Internet Explorer 10?**

You can use a polyfill like [gray](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray).

Comment: any chance we can revert this to the normal image on hover etc... I mean just apply this effect on mouseover and revert to colored image on mouseout?

Comment: Ah thanks but I meant we load the image as black and white but on hover we change it to normal...

Comment: @CamiloMartin CSS filters are only supported by Chrome 18+

Comment: @SalmanPK Ah... :/ well, good to know, thanks. At least Chrome's auto-update means we'll get this everywhere soon.

Comment: @michaellindahl Because CSS Filters are currently only supported by Webkit Nightlies and not any stable version of Safari.

Comment: *Update:* Latest stable version of Google Chrome (19) now supports CSS filters. Yay! =)

Comment: I can't get this to work for me at all - but I really don't know where you want that filters.svg file to be stored - Since I'm calling it from an external js script file, I stuck it in the same directory as the .js file.  I get no error, when I apply the filter the whole image just disappears.

Comment: @PaulGorbas `filters.svg`'s path should be relative to your html document if you are using JavaScript to add styles, so if your `filters.svg` is in yourjsdir: `yourjsdir/filters.svg` or just use an absolute url.

Comment: Is there any solution for Opera?

Comment: @Rustam No not a CSS one yet.

Comment: @Karl Horky Rolling back the edit because Firefox upto version 9/10 has a data uri bug which prevents the filter from working. And since Chrome has silent updates and older versions have like 0 marketshare, it isn't necessary to specify a version number.

Comment: @SalmanPK ah, I didn't catch that about earlier versions of Firefox. However, they have very low marketshare numbers too in the latest stats. I think it's probably worth it to drop support for 3.5-10 to save the HTTP request, based on requirements of course.

Comment: Not support to safari v.5 and opera v.12. plz help!

Comment: So, what's the solution for IE10?

Comment: Doesn't work on Opera 12, oh our dream of being cross-browser :P

Comment: @naive This will most certainly work on Opera 15 (there are no 13 or 14) because it's based on Chromium.

Comment: @SalmanPK how can I adjust the values if let's say I want it 80% grayscale? I'm not familiar with the whole 0.333 values there. Thanks.

Comment: @guisasso You don't need to use the matrix type. You can use the saturate type, which I think needs no explanation. Example for 80%, `<feColorMatrix type='saturate' values='0.8'/>`

Comment: I'm trying to get everything inside a div, regardless of what it is to be an 80% grayscale. So far I was only successful on chrome with this code -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%) brightness(100%) contrast(100%); and I can also do a transition on mouse over which is great. There is text, images, and things like a facebook like button. Everything else on IE10, opera, firefox and safaru hasn't work, but again, I'm applying it to a div. Any ideas anybody?

Comment: For posterity: @TomAuger, this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14818991/356541) has specific instructions for IE10.

Comment: for iOS, the order of your CSS matters. move ```-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);``` to the bottom, after ```filter: grayscale(1);```

Answer (score 131):

Following on from [brillout.com's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css/4027029#4027029), and also [Roman Nurik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css/979261#979261), and relaxing somewhat the the 'no SVG' requirement, you can desaturate images in Firefox using only a single SVG file and some CSS.

Your SVG file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="desaturate">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0      0      0      1 0"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

Save that as resources.svg, it can be reused from now on for any image you want to change to greyscale.

In your CSS you reference the filter using the Firefox specific `filter` property:

```
.target {
    filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate);
}
```

Add the MS proprietary ones too if you feel like it, [apply that class to any image you want to convert to greyscale (works in Firefox >3.5, IE8)](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/desaturate.html).

**edit**:  [Here's a nice blog post](http://thenewcode.com/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS) which describes using the new CSS3 `filter` property in SalmanPK's answer in concert with the SVG approach described here.  Using that approach you'd end up with something like:

```
img.desaturate{
    filter: gray; /* IE */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Old WebKit */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */
    filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate); /* older Firefox */
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
}
```

[Further browser support info here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters).

Comment: In webkit you do this: `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);` then this: `-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);` to remove it.

Comment: @SeanJA Thanks for the update, WebKit started implementing this stuff [in December](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit)

Comment: I see it in chrome beta on both my linux laptop and my win7 machine. It didn't seem to work in chrome stable in linux (but then again, it is possible linux's version is behind windows').

Comment: This method works fine for me in Chrome, but has no effect in Safari. In FF, it's making my images invisible until hover.

Answer (score 86):

For Firefox you don't need to create a filter.svg file, you can use [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Taking up the css code of the first answer gives:

```css
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: gray; /* IE6+ */
```

Take care to replace "utf-8" string by your file encoding.

This method should be faster than the other because the browser will not need to do a second HTTP request.

Comment: Just a note to save headaches: YUI Compressor strips spaces in data urls. So you might consider using another minifier if you want to use this solution.

Comment: @Malte Or maybe just replace spaces by a "%20" string ?

Comment: @mquandalle unfortunately IE10 does not support filter:gray http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/07/moving-to-standards-based-web-graphics-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: On firefox my grey is very light. Is there any way to increase the contrast or darken it slightly? Other browsers look great.

Answer (score 29):

**Update:** I made this into a full GitHub repo, including JavaScript polyfill for IE10 and IE11: https://github.com/karlhorky/gray

I originally used [SalmanPK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612047/1268612), but then created the variation below to eliminate the extra HTTP request required for the SVG file. The inline SVG works in Firefox versions 10 and above, and versions lower than 10 no longer account for even 1% of the global browser market.

I have since been keeping the solution updated on [this blog post](http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html), adding support for fading back to color, IE 10/11 support with SVG, and partial grayscale in the demo.

```
img.grayscale {
  /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");

  /* IE 6-9 */
  filter: gray;

  /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

img.grayscale.disabled {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Simplest way to achieve grayscale with CSS exclusively is via the `filter` property.

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

The property is still not fully supported and still requires the `-webkit-filter` property for support across all browsers.

Answer (score 14):

If you are able to use JavaScript, then this script may be what you are looking for. It works cross browser and is working fine for me so far. You can't use it with images loaded from a different domain.

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/

Comment: The link is broken, that's why you should always copy the content of the link instead of just referring to it, I know your answer is 12 years old and I thank you for it

Answer (score 12):

Just got the same problem today. I've initially used [SalmanPK solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612047/933464) but found out that effect differs between FF and other browsers. That's because conversion matrix works on lightness only not luminosity like filters in Chrome/IE . To my surprise I've found out that alternative and simpler solution in SVG also works in FF4+ and produces better results:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="desaturate">
    <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

With css:

```css
img {
    filter: url(filters.svg#desaturate); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}
```

One more caveat is that IE10 doesn't support "filter: gray:" in standards compliant mode anymore, so needs compatibility mode switch in headers to work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Comment: Seems a better, simpler solution - would be good if SalmanPK and mquandalle updated their solutions to this. Apparently the matrix they use [is broken](https://coderwall.com/p/-3f9gq)
<br><br>
Here's the embedded data version: 
`filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'saturate\' values=\'0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");`

Answer (score 11):

A new way to do this has been available for some time now on modern browsers.

**background-blend-mode** allows you to get some interesting effects, and one of them is grayscale conversion

The value *luminosity* , set on a white background, allows it.
(hover to see it in gray)

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/750"), white; 
    background-size: cover;
}

.test:hover {
    background-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

The luminosity is taken from the image, the color is taken from the background. Since it is always white, there is no color.

But it allows much more.

You can animate the effect setting 3 layers. The first one will be the image, and the second will be a white-black gradient. If you apply a multiply blend mode on this, you will get a white result as before on the white part, but the original image on the black part (multiply by white gives white, multiplying by black has no effect.)

On the white part of the gradient, you get the same effect as before. On the black part of the gradient, you are blending the image over itself, and the result is the unmodified image.

Now, all that is needed is to move the gradient to get this effect dynamic: (hover to see it in color)

```css
div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}

.test {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/750"), 
linear-gradient(0deg, white 33%, black 66%), url("http://placekitten.com/1000/750"); 
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0%, 0px 0px;
    background-size: cover, 100% 300%, cover;
    background-blend-mode: luminosity, multiply;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.test:hover {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 66%, 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

[reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/)

[compatibility matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode)

Comment: @Andy    I began my answer saying *in modern browsers*

Comment: How can you apply that if an `img` tag is used for the image not `background: url()`

Comment: @MohammadElbanna You need to use mix-blend-mode instead of background-blend-mode

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't look like it's possible (yet), even with CSS3 or proprietary `-webkit-` or `-moz-` CSS properties.

However, I did find [this post from last June](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roc/archives/2008/06/applying_svg_ef.html) that used SVG filters on HTML. Not available in any current browser (the demo hinted at a custom WebKit build), but very impressive as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 7):

In Internet Explorer use the filter property.

In webkit and Firefox there is currently no way to desatuarte an image solely with CSS.
so you will need to use either canvas or SVG for a client side solution.

But I think using SVG is more elegant. check out my blog post for the SVG solution that works for both Firefox and webkit:
http://webdev.brillout.com/2010/10/desaturate-image-without-javascript.html

And strictly speaking since SVG is HTML the solution is pure html+css :-)

Comment: hi brillout. I noticed that your grayscale actually fails at safari. Any followup? Thanks

Comment: SVG is ***not*** HTML. It's a whole different spec.

Comment: @CamiloMartin [Here is SVG in the HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-map-element.html#svg-0).

Comment: @robertc That link is about putting an SVG in an HTML, but here's the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/) and here's the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html/). The fact that both are similar to each other (or, to XML) doesn't mean they are the same thing...

Comment: But this doesn't affect the fact you're right about using SVG filters :) In the near future (or now already, didn't check) we'll even have SVG filters for any HTML element in stable browsers (the fact we didn't have them already speaks a lot about the separation of both formats - the blur filter in particular will rock).

Comment: @CamiloMartin No, [this is the HTML spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/), the same one I linked to.  HTML parsers are required to understand SVG elements.

Comment: But it links to the SVG spec in the [reference](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/references.html#refsSVG)... It doesn't define SVG, just says that browsers should parse it. It's like Javascript or CSS in that regard.

Answer (score 7):

For people who are asking about the ignored IE10+ support in other answers, checkout this piece of CSS:

```css
img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}

svg {
    background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg);
}

svg image:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Applied on this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Grayscaling in Internet Explorer 10+</title>

</head>
<body>

    <p>IE10 with inline SVG</p>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 400 377" width="400" height="377">
      <defs>
         <filter id="filtersPicture">
           <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" />
           <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="377" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s1600/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg" />
    </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

For more demos, checkout IE testdrive's [CSS3 Graphics section](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm) and this old IE blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this way help you

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

[w3schools.org](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

Answer (score 3):

It's in fact easier to do it with IE if I remember correctly using a proprietary CSS property. Try this `FILTER: Gray` from http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml

The method by [Ax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css/609302#609302) simply makes the image transparent and has a black background behind it. I'm sure you could argue this is grayscale.

Although you didn't want to use Javascript, I think you'll have to use it. You could also use a server side language to do it.

Comment: I do not even have a Windows box, so thanks, but that's of little use to me.

Comment: In that case, you can look at it with a Virtual Machine with IE, implement ax's method or use canvas... note that grayscaling on large images with canvas can be quite taxing on the Javascript engine.

Comment: `filter: gray` is present in Internet Explorer since *Version 4*. They have taken a lot of crap for their product - rightly! - but they were really ahead of their time with this stuff

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use Javascript, then you can use a canvas to convert the image to grayscale. Since Firefox and Safari support `<canvas>`, it should work.

So I googled "canvas grayscale", and the first result was http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html which seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

support for native CSS filters in webkit has been added from the current version 19.0.1084.46

so -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) will work and which is easier than SVG approach for webkit...

Answer (score 2):

Based on [robertc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028908/1784053):

To get **proper** conversion from colored image to grayscale image instead of using matrix like this:

```
0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
0      0      0      1 0
```

You should use conversion matrix like this:

```
0.299 0.299 0.299 0
0.587 0.587 0.587 0
0.112 0.112 0.112 0
0     0     0     1
```

This should work fine for all the types of images based on RGBA (red-green-blue-alpha) model.

For more information why you should use matrix I posted more likely that the robertc's one check following links:

- [The luminance and colour difference signals](https://intranet.rave.ac.uk/download/attachments/9116/The+Y,+U+and+V+signals.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1180887337667)
- [Margus's answer for question: "greyscalevalue in colorvalue" @stackoverflow part: **Edit 2: @Hans Passant**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410393/1784053)
- [Charles A. Bouman - Purdue university - Analog TV page 20 & 21](https://engineering.purdue.edu/%7Ebouman/ece637/notes/guestlecture/Torres/Analog_TV.pdf)
- [And here you can find some C# and VB codes](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx)

Comment: I agree 0.3333 is wrong; `0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0` appears to be the equivalent of `<fecolormatrix type="saturate" values="0">`

Comment: The link to "The luminance and colour difference signals" is also broken. I couldn't find a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mixin for LESS that will let you choose any opacity. Fill in the variables yourself for plain CSS at different percentages.

**Neat hint here**, it uses the saturate type for the matrix so you don't need to do anything fancy to change the percentage.

```
.saturate(@value:0) {
    @percent: percentage(@value);

    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='saturate'%20values='@value'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: grayscale(@percent); /* Current draft standard */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(@percent); /* New WebKit */
    -moz-filter: grayscale(@percent);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(@percent);
    -o-filter: grayscale(@percent);
}
```

Then use it:

```
img.desaturate {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    .saturate(0);
    &:hover {
        .saturate(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to other's answers, it's possible to desaturate an image half the way on FF without SVG's *matrix's* headaches:

```
<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="$v" />
```

Where `$v` is between `0` and `1`. It's equivalent to `filter:grayscale(50%);`.

Live example:

```css
.desaturate {
    filter: url("#desaturate");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
}
figcaption{
    background: rgba(55, 55, 136, 1);
    padding: 4px 98px 0 18px;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100%;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="desaturate">
   <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0.4"/>
  </filter>
</svg>

<figure>
  <figcaption>Original</figcaption>
  <img src="http://www.placecage.com/c/500/200"/>
  </figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Half grayed</figcaption>
  <img class="desaturate" src="http://www.placecage.com/c/500/200"/>
</figure>
```

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need use so many prefixes for full use, because if you choose prefix for old firefox, you don't need use prefix for new firefox.

So for full use, enough use this code:

```
img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}

img.grayscale.disabled {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

be **An alternative for older browser** could be to use mask produced by pseudo-elements or inline tags.

Absolute positionning hover an  img (or text area wich needs no click nor selection) can closely mimic effects of color scale , *via rgba() or translucide png* .

It will not give one single color scale, but will shades color out of range.

test on code pen with 10 different colors via pseudo-element, last is gray . http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/nqpDd (reload to switch to another image)

Answer (score 0):

One terrible but workable solution: render the image using a Flash object, which then gives you all the transformations possible in Flash.

**If** your users are using bleeding-edge browsers and **if** Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4 support it (I don't know that either do/will), you could adjust the CSS *color-profile* attribute of the image, setting it to a grayscale ICC profile URL. But that's a lot of if's!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the functions of jFunc - use the function "jFunc_CanvasFilterGrayscale"
http://jfunc.com/jFunc-functions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery plugin. Although, this is not a pure HTML and CSS solution, but it is a lazy way to achieve what you want. You can customize your greyscale to best suit your usage. Use it as follow:

```
$("#myImageID").tancolor();
```

There's an interactive [demo](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/). You can play around with it.

Check out the documentation on the usage, it is pretty simple. [docs](https://github.com/nicolaisi/tancolor)

Answer (score 0):

For grayscale as a percent in Firefox, use [saturate filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix) instead: (search for 'saturate')

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='saturate'><feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='saturate' values='0.2' /></filter></svg>#saturate"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you, or someone else facing a similar problem in future are open to PHP.
(I know you said HTML/CSS, but maybe you are already using PHP in the backend)
Here is a PHP solution:

I got it from the PHP GD library and added some variable to automate the process...

```php
<?php
$img = @imagecreatefromgif("php.gif");

if ($img) $img_height = imagesy($img);
if ($img) $img_width = imagesx($img);

// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Copy and merge - Gray = 20%
imagecopymergegray($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, 20);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);

?>
```

Comment: @Tom, based on the votes and favorites on the original question, the OP isn't the only person who wondered if this is possible.  Sure, this answer might bend the rules, but I don't see the point in downvoting an answer that might be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: @Tom, I though though it might no be an exact reply to the question,it  might come in handy as it actually "solves" the problem of the grayscale without the "hassle" of javascript, maybe he didnt even consider or knew about PHP GD, no harm intended. @mlms13 that was the point exactly, thanks :)

Comment: That's my bad , "thought" about _that other users can benefit from this post_ slipped away from my mind.. Apologies @Trufa.

Comment: @Tom don´t worry about it!! I realize this answer is in the limit of relevant and this things might happen! Thanks for the apology! :)

Comment: That did help me, put me on the right track after a few other dead ends. I found that using "imagefilter($source, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);" gave a much better result though. (PHP 5 only)

Comment: Voted down, since it's virtually off topic. Grayscaling an image on the server side is completely different from CSS/HTML.