# Display color picture as monochrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to display a color picture as greyscale using Html/Css?  Ie. no server side processing.

Edited: monochrome -> greyscale

Comment: You could do it with a `<canvas>` probably; just run through the pixels normalizing intensity to monochrome. Not all browsers support `<canvas>` however.

Comment: I assume you mean gray-scale, not monochrome -- the latter would be just blacks and whites.

Comment: @Pointy, canvas would work for my purposes actually.   And yes, crosley, I meant greyscale thanks for the correction. Thanks ;p

Comment: @tcrosley yes right, of course. Sorry. @John the "image data" format for `<canvas>` is really simple - you get an array of values, such that each group of four (counting up from the start of the array) is a pixel.  The first three values are RGB (0..255) and the fourth is alpha. Thus you'd get the image data, process it, and put it back.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css , `<canvas>` is new i guess but besides that everything was said in that thread

Comment: Maybe you solved it by know but I found what I think is an interesting solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to upload a greyscale picture in the first place.  If this is for some sort of hover task, take a look at creating a [CSS sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).  I understand this doesn't answer the question fully, but I can't for the life of me understand why you need client side image manipulation.

Comment: Lots of good solutions here but this one achieves what I'm looking for - no image swapping, no pixel manipulation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

http://snipplr.com/view/2836/grayscale-img-with-css-crossbrowser/

Might be a good alternative...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to canvas, in at least some browsers (such as Firefox), you can use SVG filters.  For an example, see [this slide](http://dbaron.org/talks/2009-03-15-css3-sxsw/slide-25.xhtml) (button 2 invokes a filter that does pretty much what you want).

Answer (score 1):

I think i found another very good way with PHP!

Check this out:

```
<?php
$img = @imagecreatefromgif("php.gif");

if ($img) $img_height = imagesy($img);
if ($img) $img_width = imagesx($img);

// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Copy and merge - Gray = 20%
imagecopymergegray($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, 20);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);

?>
```

I remembered your question when I ways playing around with the PHP GD lib.

Good luck!! tell me if its any good...

Trufa

Answer (score 1):

This is not greyscale, but opacity gives to the user the sense of disabled:

Stilesheet:

```
.opaque { 
 -khtml-opacity:.50; 
 -moz-opacity:.50; 
 -ms-filter:”alpha(opacity=50)”; 
  filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
  opacity:.50; 
  }
```

Html:

```
<img class="opaque".... />
```

This solution is cross-browser, works with all recent browser, IE8, old versions of Safari.