# How to apply the grayscale jquery plugin to a background image?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I want to use the [jquery-grayscale](https://github.com/josefrichter/jquery-grayscale/blob/master/js/grayscale.js) that converts images colors to their respective grayscale. Use it is very simple, identify the image and apply the plugin:

```
$('#my-icon').grayscale()
```

But how to do it if the image is defined in a css file as a **background-image**?

```
#my-icon{ background-image:url('../Images/my-icon.png'); }
```

Thanks.-

EDIT: Of course any other way to convert to grayscale these icons is useful too. Any idea?

Comment: You could just convert the background image to grayscale with Photoshop, no?

Comment: That won't do if there are lots of images, for example if users can upload images too.

Comment: Yes, the truth is that my client could change these images at any moment, so I must have a global solution, thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using [this plugin](https://github.com/blindgaenger/jquery-grayscale/blob/master/lib/jquery.grayscale.js)? Looking at the code it only seems to support `<img src="...">` images so you'll either have to modify it or hope that someone else does.

Comment: good point about gives the link to the library (done now) No, it's about another [library](https://github.com/josefrichter/jquery-grayscale/blob/master/js/grayscale.js) , but both looks very similar.

Comment: Okay, they both seem to be pretty identical in what they do. Both expect the selector target to have a `src` attribute which is changed in the end to point to the canvas holding the grayscale version of the image.

Answer (score 2):

(I know its an old post, but for the record...)
If you want to switch from color to grayscale instantly, check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340159/greyscale-background-css-images). If you want to switch them gradually, then use jquery and canvas.

This is an example code based on [HTML5 Grayscale Image Hover](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover) site, as their version only supports < img > elements,  I did this code to use 'background' css rule instead:

HTML:

```
<div class="gray"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.gray {
    width: 300px;
    height: 00px;
    opacity: 0;
    background-image: url(images/yourimage.jpg);
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $ = jQuery;
    // On window load. This waits until images have loaded which is essential
    $(window).load(function(){

        // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load
        $("div.gray").animate({opacity:1},500);

        // clone colored image, convert it to grayscale and place the cloned one on top
        $('div.gray').each(function(){
            var div = $(this);
            var bg = div.css('background-image');
            bg = /^url\((['"]?)(.*)\1\)$/.exec(bg);
            bg = bg ? bg[2] : "";
            if(bg) {
                var el = $("<div></div>");
                div.append(el);
                el.addClass('color').css({
                    "position":"absolute",
                    "z-index":"100",
                    "opacity":"0",
                    "background-image":"url('"+bg+"')"
                });
                div.css('background-image',"url('"+grayscale(bg)+"')");
            }
        });

        // Fade image 
        $('div.gray').mouseover(function(){
            var div = $(this);
            div.find('div.color').css({
                "width":div.width(),
                "height":div.height(),
                "top":div.position().top,
                "left":div.position().left,
            }).stop().animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        })
        $('div.color').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 1000);
        });
    });

    // Grayscale w canvas method
    function grayscale(src){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = src;
        canvas.width = imgObj.width;
        canvas.height = imgObj.height;
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }
});
```

The "url(...)" parser was obtained from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809876/can-i-get-divs-background-image-url). It does not handle any kind of value, but works with simple paths. You may modify the regex. if you need more.

You can see the example code in JSBin: http://jsbin.com/qusotake/1/edit?html,css,js
**However** it doesn't work because of domain restrictions (with the image). Please download the code and the image and execute it in your local web server.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937216/display-color-picture-as-monochrome).

And because of performance reasons I chose not to convert the image to grayscale on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do it in client side.

Comment: @NomikOS That's cool - follow the link I gave you, there are suggestions on how to do it client-side