# Apply grayscale filter to div

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image: quick example]

Trying to apply a grayscale filter to the div that is over top of the main background. Wondering if this is possible at all with jQuery, CSS3, or HTML5. I was playing with a few of the new CSS3/HTML5 technologies but to no success.

I can't save it as two images because the background needs to stretch full-size, so it won't be exactly the same on every screen.

I'm working on an early draft and I am just wondering if I should kill this idea. If you point me in the right direction I can figure it out.

Comment: Once solution has just occurred to me, rather simple one, but not ideal. Save two images, color and b/w, and simply write some creative math to `background-position` the b/w into place.

Comment: if your background needs to stretch you need _more_ clouds, not stretched ones...

Comment: The graphic is massive, the screenshot only shows a small portion.

Comment: For a "canvas+jquery with transition effect" solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704415/how-to-apply-the-grayscale-jquery-plugin-to-a-background-image/24949717#24949717

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't apply a "grayscale everything behind me" filter in CSS.

If you don't mind full screen with loss of aspect ratio (which may not matter depending on your cloud image) here is a technique. It places a div on top of the background that is half the width and uses `background-size:200% 100%` so that it will size the same as the background. Then we apply CSS3 grayscale and the older versions of it. Then a pseudo-element on top to darken the image.

Tested and works in: Chrome 25, Firefox, IE9 (I assume 7, 8 as well) currently.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JX2P/2/)

[image]

```
.gray {
    background:url(https://www.google.com.au/logos/2013/maria_sibylla_merians_366th_birthday_-1256008-hp.jpg);
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:200% 100%;
    position:relative;

    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}
.gray:after {
    display:block;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:.7;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    background:url(https://www.google.com.au/logos/2013/maria_sibylla_merians_366th_birthday_-1256008-hp.jpg);
    height:100%;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
html {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, it's a much more optimized solution than I had come up since the the graphics are very large.

Comment: Would need a bit of work to get support right but the idea seems pretty solid to me.

Answer (score 14):

You can use CSS filters:

```
#mydiv{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Keep in mind that this works on Chrome and Safari at the moment.

More info: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: update 2021: works for all major browsers except IE

Comment: hello from 2023

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by applying a mix-blend-mode to the div on the top, with a white background :

```
.divOnTop {
     background: white;
     mix-blend-mode: saturation;
}
```

Be careful to the z-index.

For more on mix-blend-mode :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 2):

CSS makes it simple to provide 'grey-scale' or transparent backgrounds using rgba values. Alternatively you can use transparent images.

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/TtSUD/

in your css you apply an rgba value to a background as such:

```
#background_div{background-color:rgba(150,150,150,0.5);}
```

The first three values are for the amount of red green and blue, the fourth value is the percentage of opaqueness. 1 = 100% opaque, 0.5 = 50% opaque/transparent.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

> [backdrop-filter](https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter)

However, it has mixed support at the time of writing - Chrome, Edge, Safari, Opera, but surprisingly not Firefox. Give it some time for major browsers, I guess. I wouldn't expect IE to ever support it, though.

Here is an example where the first row of blocks are in color, and then the second row of blocks are *also* in color, but are covered by an overlay that uses backdrop-filter on it.

```css
.content, .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.content.second-content, .overlay {
  top: 50%;
}

.overlay {
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(1);
}

.content .color {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="color red"></div>
  <div class="color blue"></div>
  <div class="color yellow"></div>
</div>
<div class="content second-content">
  <div class="color red"></div>
  <div class="color blue"></div>
  <div class="color yellow"></div>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2022: You can now grayscale everything with vast support for browsers (except IE).
You do not have to use the `webkit` prefix either:

```
filter: grayscale(1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make the background image a greyscale version of the image behind it. That should work. You just have to position the backgrounds right.