# Black and White background CSS

Tags: css, background

I have a background image on the `<body>` block.

I want to make it black and white by using the webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);

But when I'm applying this filter to the body block, all the images on my site becomes black and white too. I want only my background to be black and white. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert an absolutely positioned div and apply the background to that.

```
<body>
<div id="BG"></div>
....
other code here
....
</body>


#BG{
   position:fixed;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   background-image:(yourimage);
   webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
   z-index:-500;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5d5w/6/

Don't forget to add filters for non-webkit browsers too. See:
[Greyscale Background Css Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340159/greyscale-background-css-images)

Comment: Do you you need to set the z-index for this? Where will the image show up? Behind the text?

Comment: This solution will prevent text-selection on this page.

Comment: I have fixed background. If I set position: absolute, background won't be fixed..

Comment: What about `position:fixed` on the background div?

Comment: Thanks!! Helped. With position: fixed all works fine!