# How can I make the background color of the body black and white

Tags: css

I want to change the color of my body and I want to make it black and white. This the code that I am using at the moment:

```
font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("http://vlr.tynt.com/?format=txt&key=284d869ffe43382ebe88a02cabb697ab&u=http%3A%2F%2Ft.wallpaperweb.org%2Fwallpaper%2Fnature%2F1920x1080%2FPacific_Sunset_Pismo_Beach_California.jpg&subId=cyfIqK8eur4kvOacwqm_6r&txt=&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpaperweb.org%2Fwallpaper%2Fnature%2Fpacific-sunset-pismo-beach-california_40871.htm&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.al%2F&title=Nature%3A%20Pacific%20Sunset%2C%20Pismo%20Beach%2C%20California%2C%20desktop%20wallpaper%20nr.%2040871");
    color: white;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
```

I have googled a lot but the websites show me the image when it is like a random image in the body not as a background image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Greyscale Background Css Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340159/greyscale-background-css-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a filter on the `body` background, however there's a hacky way to do it using the `:before` pseudo selector like so:

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
  body:before {
    content: "";
    background: url("http://vlr.tynt.com/?format=txt&key=284d869ffe43382ebe88a02cabb697ab&u=http%3A%2F%2Ft.wallpaperweb.org%2Fwallpaper%2Fnature%2F1920x1080%2FPacific_Sunset_Pismo_Beach_California.jpg&subId=cyfIqK8eur4kvOacwqm_6r&txt=&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpaperweb.org%2Fwallpaper%2Fnature%2Fpacific-sunset-pismo-beach-california_40871.htm&ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.al%2F&title=Nature%3A%20Pacific%20Sunset%2C%20Pismo%20Beach%2C%20California%2C%20desktop%20wallpaper%20nr.%2040871");
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
  }
```

**Note that this solution does not support IE or Edge.**

Another solution would be to create an element with the filter applied and use absolute positioning to put it behind the content.

## [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340159/greyscale-background-css-images)