# Fading background image from grey to colour after loading a page

Tags: css, background-image, transition, fading

I am trying to get an effect of fading background (once) from greyscale to colour after page is loaded up. I came up with this, but doesn't work:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: #ffffff url('http://www.itgeared.com/images/content/1481-1.jpg') no-repeat top;
        background-attachment: fixed; 
        animation: filter-animation 8s;
        -webkit-animation: filter-animation 8s;            
    }    
    .content {height:2000px;}

@keyframes filter-animation {
   0% ,75%{
   filter: grayscale(1);
}

 100% {
  filter: grayscale(0);
  }

}


@-webkit-keyframes filter-animation {
 0%, 75% {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
 }

 100% {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
 }

}
```

and html:

```
<div class="content">
    . <br/>. <br/>. <br/>. <br/>
</div>
```

I'm trying to achieve something like this: [link here](http://www.silvabokis.com/cover-page-fade-in).

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/ht3ndg8k/)

Thanks

Comment: Read more here, it's an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21899030/6908117

Comment: thanks but I didn't want to rebuild the whole page (I copied only basics from it). The answer below solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You may want to have a different layout for your image when you are in a mobile or tablet so you can add this media query at the end of the CSS document.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    .img {
        position: fixed;
        width: auto;
        height:80%;
        animation: filter-animation 8s;
        -webkit-animation: filter-animation 8s;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}
```

So the new CSS class `img` will override the old one when the width of the screen is less than `768px`.

***Note: Please play around with this CSS to suit your need. But this query works for mobile and tablets and just needs minor tweaking!***

**Old Answer:**

Instead of using `background-image` which cannot be used with the above CSS try an fixed positioned image for your page instead which basically does the same thing. Here is the code for doing it.

***Note: Positioning the image needs to be adjusted to suit your requirement. like you can have either `height:100%;width:auto` or `height:auto;width:100%`, this needs to be tweaked as per your need.***

```css
html,
body {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: filter-animation 8s;
  -webkit-animation: filter-animation 8s;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
}

@keyframes filter-animation {
  0%,
  75% {
    filter: grayscale(1);
  }
  100% {
    filter: grayscale(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes filter-animation {
  0%,
  75% {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="http://www.itgeared.com/images/content/1481-1.jpg" />
<div class="content">
  .
  <br/>.
  <br/>.
  <br/>.
  <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: @NaurenMurali thanks. One more question. How can I center horizontally the background image? I'm doing this on bootstrap and the main content of the image is in the center, so when I use mobile it shows the left side of the image instead of center of it. How to center that image?

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski Please give me some time! I will provide resolution

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski Thanks for waiting, I have updated my answer with a media query for centering on mobile and tablet, please use this CSS class and adjust it to suit your need, hope this help you resolve the issue completely!