# Image Greyscale with CSS & re-color on mouse-over?

Tags: css, mouseover, grayscale

I am looking to take an icon that is colored (and will be a link) and turn it greyscale until the user places their mouse over the icon (where it would then color the image).

Is this possible to do, and in a way that is IE & Firefox supported?

Comment: Almost duplicated... http://stackoverflow.com/q/609273/670377

Comment: wouldn't it be a more interesting effect if you did it the other way around? let the mouse cursor be kinda like a magic wand that brings color to a dark world?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

There are numerous methods of accomplishing this, which I'll detail with a few examples below.

### Pure CSS (using only one colored image)

```
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

img.grayscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```css
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
  /* Firefox 3.5+, IE10 */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
  /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Fix for transition flickering */
}

img.grayscale:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}

svg {
  background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg);
}

svg image {
  transition: all .6s ease;
}

svg image:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE6-9</p>
<img class="grayscale" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s1600/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg" width="400">
<p>IE10 with inline SVG</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 400 377" width="400" height="377">
  <defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
       <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" />
       <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="377" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s1600/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg" />
   </svg>
```

You can find [an article related to this technique here](http://www.karlhorky.com/2012/06/cross-browser-image-grayscale-with-css.html).

### Pure CSS (using a grayscale and colored images)

This approach requires two copies of an image: one in grayscale and the other in full color. Using the CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) psuedoselector, you can update the background of your element to toggle between the two:

```
#yourimage { 
    background: url(../grayscale-image.png);
}
#yourImage:hover { 
    background: url(../color-image.png};
}
```

```css
#google {
  background: url('http://www.google.com/logos/keystroke10-hp.png');
  height: 95px;
  width: 275px;
  display: block;
  /* Optional for a gradual animation effect */
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#google:hover {
  background: url('https://graphics217b.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/logo1w.png');
}
```

```html
<a id='google' href='http://www.google.com'></a>
```

This could also be accomplished by using a Javascript-based hover effect such as jQuery's [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) function in the same manner.

### Consider a Third-Party Library

The [**desaturate**](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/desaturate/) library is a common library that allows you to easily switch between a grayscale version and full-colored version of a given element or image.

Comment: If said images need to be linked to other website tho, how could this be done if the images are set as backgrounds?

Comment: It would work the same way, check the demo out under section 1. If you have any other questions I'll be glad to help.

Comment: guys, did anyone noticed that this isn't working in safari? I just checked and found this issue, is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 16):

Answered here: [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

You don't even need to use two images which sounds like a pain or an image manipulation library, you can do it with cross browser support (current versions) and just use CSS.  This is a progressive enhancement approach which just falls back to color versions on older browsers:

```
img {
  filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
  /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
}
img:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

and filters.svg file like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="grayscale">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7):

I use the following code on http://www.diagnomics.com/

Smooth transition from b/w to color with magnifying effect (scale)

```
    img.color_flip {
      filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
      filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
      -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    img.color_flip:hover {
      filter: none;
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

Comment: Works great in webkit browsers! Your code does not work for me in Firefox browser but then again, I think it has something to do with an SVG file and I'm using a bitmap in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/num04rya/10/ Something strange though - the transition effect in Safari makes the image 'jerk' on rollover....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [sprite](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) which has both version—the colored and the monochrome—stored into it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a demo. Even works in IE7:

http://james.padolsey.com/demos/grayscale/

and

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/grayscaling-in-non-ie-browsers/