# How to create colored image mouseover on black/white images (in JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering if there are any good solutions available for turning a color image into a black/white solid state and allowing it to transition back into a colored image on mouse over using jQuery?

I tried a CSS method as described here: [Image Greyscale with CSS & re-color on mouse-over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over), but I'm not having much luck with it.

Here is the current site: http://frixel.com/wp/ - I am trying to create the effect on the gallery grid.

Comment: To help someone answer the question, I suggest posting the relevant HTML, CSS, and javascript in your question.

Comment: The example you posted uses a SVG image, and you can manipulate those. With a normal image you could replace the SRC for example...

Comment: Just have two versions of the image, one color and one black-and-white, and change the src attribute on hover. That will be the fastest/most reliable way to handle this.

Answer (score 6):

Hey you are talking about CSS filters... this what you need 
add this code to your **main stylesheet** file ;)

```
.portfolio:hover {
filter: grayscale(100%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe a solution would be to use this plugin:

http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/

a demo with carousel:
http://interio.tohidgolkar.com/shortcodes/clients-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code, It helps to create colored image mouseover on black/white image.:

```
<style>
.blk-white{-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); filter: grayscale(100%);}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_blackwhite(obj) {
$(obj).addClass("blk-white");
}
function display_colorphoto(obj) {
$(obj).removeClass("blk-white");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="change-colorphoto-black-white1.jpg" onMouseOver="display_blackwhite(this)" onMouseOut="display_colorphoto(this)" width="350"/>
<img src="change-colorphoto-black-white2.png" onMouseOver="display_blackwhite(this)" onMouseOut="display_colorphoto(this)" width="350"/>
```