# css hover filter not working in ie

Tags: image, wordpress, internet-explorer, hover, svg-filters

Hi I have a problem I haven't been able to solve. I want my thumbnails displayed as grayscale and then in color on hover. The original image is color. It works in Chrome and FF. It will not work in IE.

http://rubowarkitekter.dk/?projekt_type=undervisning

I've added a filter to my thumbnails as explained in the accepted answer in this thread:
[Image Greyscale with CSS & re-color on mouse-over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over)

```
#projekt-image img { width: 163.33px; height: 120px; filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */ filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */ -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */ }
```

and for hover

```
#projekt-image img:hover { filter: none;   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); }
```

This is my code

```
<div id="projekt-image"><a href="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'rubowtax', '1798', apply_filters('the_permalink', get_permalink())); ?>"><?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {    kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'rubow_projekt' );} ?></a> </div>
```

In IE8 and 9 the images are displayed in color and nothing happens on hover.

Please let me know if you have any idea of what I could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create an additional stylesheet just to target IE. Have the images be a background image on css and replace the image on :hover with a color one.

To target IE browsers:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Only IE would read the additional stylesheet and you can target specific versions of IE:
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try that if I can't get the other thing to work. But I should be able to get the current code to work.