# CSS Hover Grayscale Not activating

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image Grayscale by default an on hover fade into color. I'm having issues with it taking into consideration that I want the hover to only associate to images.

```
/* MAKE ALL FEATURED IMAGES BLACK AND WHITE */
.banner-wrap .featured-thumbnail {

    width: 270px !important;
    height: 149px !important;

}

.featured-thumbnail img{

  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

.featured-thumbnail img:hover{

  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Comment: I found this googleing making grayscale to color in css hover 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with the Images inside the div.

Comment: seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/nDU37/

Comment: Managed to get it working by making the elements !Important