# How to have 2 images alligned next to each other in HTML

Tags: html

The title basically says my problem. I basically want to have 2 images aligned next to eachother, one on the left and one on the right; I would just use `<img src>` but I want the alignment to be properly done. I have been looking around but I can't seem to find anything related to my search.

Also, if there's a way to make a displayed image in black and white, and when hovered over; it displays the correct image (which is in color) - just to give it an effect?

Comment: Also, you mean vertically-aligned, right? Are images same dimensions?

Comment: What do you consider "proper alignment"?

Comment: Why would you use img src for alignment?

Comment: About the grey-scale effect, take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over)

Answer (score 0):

About align your 2 images you can try to apply float property at CSS like:

```
.image {
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5ajFK/

The `<img src>` is wrapped in a span and it is positioned `absolute`. The black and white effects can be implemented using CSS filter which activates when the mouse is placed on the image.

```
$('img').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('desaturate');    
});
$('img').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('desaturate');    
});
```

The CSS for b&w effect:

```
img.desaturate { -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```