# grayscale in chrome via css

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, svg

Is there a way to make a grayscale image in chrome via css?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css) but doesn't work on latest version of chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

support for native CSS filters in webkit has been added from the current version 19.0.1084.46

so -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) will work and which is better and easier approach than SVG for webkit...

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be svg with a level of indirection.

Basically, `<img src="wrapper.svg"/>` where wrapper.svg applies an svg filter to the svg, and the svg has an image element pointing to your raster image. Works in Opera, Chrome, Firefox and probably IE10 (untested).

Here's a [demo](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/filters/make-grayscale-filter.svg#url=boston.jpg). You can pass in your own url if you `encodeURIComponent` it first. Note though that for passing in parameters to work it relies on scripting being enabled, so if you need to use it in <img> elements or in a css background image you'd need to generate the svg files on the server.

Comment: Wow, that's really sweet! Just a heads up; I embedded it and had to make two minor tweaks, remove `.toLowerCase()` for case sensitive urls and `arr` should be an object `{}`.

Comment: I want a grayscale effect when hovering the image.Is this possible with your solution?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example above with the suggested fixes, and added an animated example: http://dahlström.net/svg/filters/make-grayscale-filter-on-hover.svg#url=boston.jpg (worked fine in Opera and Firefox. Chrome seemed to not get the mouseout events, possibly this is only when loaded standalone though, and IE doesn't support SVG Animations). It's quite possible to do the animation with scripting too though.

Comment: yes it seems scripting is the only way for now for a cross browser solution

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but Chrome 18 will support [css filters](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/12/CSS-Filter-Effects-Landing-in-WebKit) (released later this year). SVG filters is only supported by Firefox. You should be able to find a consistent canvas+javascript solution though.

EDIT: See Erik Dahlström's post for alternate solution.

Comment: SVG filters are supported by all browsers (counting IE10 too) in SVG content. But it's true that at the moment Firefox is the only browser that supports use of svg filters directly on HTML content.

Comment: True, I should have been more specific about the context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an HTML5 solution. Supported by current versions of Chrome: http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/