# filtre SVG apply to a canvas dont work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, svg, filter, html5-canvas

I have chrome version : 33.0.1750.117

before this version the filter SVG applied to my canvas work but now it work on firefox but not on chrome

you can test with this example

[example grayscale filter on canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/YZ66e/5/)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix"  
     values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.001 
             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.001  
             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.001  
             0 0 0 1 0.001"/>

</svg>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#myCanvas:hover {
        filter: url(#grayscale); /* Firefox */      
        -ms-filter: url(#grayscale); /* IE */
        -webkit-filter: url(#grayscale); /* Webkit */
        }
```

Comment: Confirming your results: Hover==greyscale in FF27, no image at all in Chrome33 and image but no greyscale in IE11.

Comment: in chrome if you remove the svg tags it will be appear the image ,

Comment: in the latest version I can use the filter svg on canvas but if you go to chrome://flags and desable 2D canvas it will work

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 33.0.1750.117 m on Windows 7 for me.  (Once you scroll down past the empty SVG, that is.  Maybe that was @markE's problem?)  Nothing on IE11, but that's because IE doesn't yet support SVG filters on HTML elements.  The [ms-filter property is unrelated and deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Just tried enabling/disabling the 2D Graphics acceleration option.  It didn't stop the filter from working on my system, but I suppose that certain graphics acceleration systems could be interfering.  What OS / graphics card are you using?

Comment: the chip type : Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);`

See [grayscale in chrome via css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874422/grayscale-in-chrome-via-css).

Comment: I need to use filter SVG because I combine with RGB filter, and I dont think there 's a filter RGB with -webkit-filter to fix manually the degree of red or blue or green

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working in Chrome 33, it's just that the SVG element is in your way. Try width="0" height="0" on the SVG element. (Nit: you're also missing a  close tag.)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
 <filter id="grayscale" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix"  values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.001 0.3333 0.3333    0.3333 0 0.001 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0.001 0 0 0 1 0.001"/>
 </filter>
</svg>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2nPW/