# Is there a way to change an image's color scale in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if there is a way to change an image color scale in `JavaScript`?  Say you want to make it warmer or cooler depending upon the user's input.  If there is a way in jquery or html5 that would be fine as well.  Anyone know how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: You should look into html5 canvas. An easy trick is to modify the opacity.

Comment: With canvas you could change each pixels color value according to some rules. It's certainly possible. There also seems to be SVG solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css

Comment: Try to do google, Do your work, analyse what went wrong perhaps have the issue and post it in SO. and I request you to read the SO Terms.

Comment: @Dustin: Downvoting questions does not cost any rep...

Comment: @DustinGraham You don't lose rep for downvoting questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I do remember reading that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 has lot more features than what you just looking for. Anyhow the CANVAS container is the solution that i could say, where you can play with the color, pixels of image. . Have a look at this [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/). Hope this can help you to start

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not in jquery itself but there is very cool js library for manipulating images called `pixastic`.
http://www.pixastic.com/
Try to search documentation for option you need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want to change the saturation. I tried Pixastic but it's broken in my browsers, Chrome, Opera and IE7.

Caman JS looks like it delivers, at least judging from the demo page

http://camanjs.com/examples