# CSS -webkit-filter doesn't work in Chrome 22.0

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, filter, webkit

i have this code and it does not work Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m.

```
<div id='botonera'>
    <button id='restaurar'>Restaurar</button>
    <button id='blur'>Blur</button>
    <button id='greyscale'>Greyscale</button>
    <button id='sepia'>Sepia</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');

    document.getElementById('restaurar').onclick = function() {
        imagen.className = 'restaurar';
    }
    document.getElementById('blur').onclick = function() {
        imagen.className = 'blur';
    }
    document.getElementById('greyscale').onclick = function() {
        imagen.className = 'greyscale';
    }
    document.getElementById('sepia').onclick = function() {
        imagen.className = 'sepia';
    }
</script>
```

Only greyscale doesn't work, blur, sepia an "restore" work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be spelling `grayscale` as `greyscale` in your CSS. Both spellings are correct, but only the first one will work.

```
.greyscale {  
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Comment: Since this is a class name, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @JanDvorak: My bad. It should be changed for the webkit filter.

Comment: I love "Both ... are correct, but only the first one will work" :-)

Comment: ohh, sorry, you are right, i was missing a letter in the filter, "greyscale", thanks!

Usefull link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css