# Using Grayscal hover effect, not working properly in FF or IE

Tags: css, hover

The effect looks great in Chrome but fails in IE and FF. Please view this link in multiple browsers:

http://thebc.co/our-work

`.portfolio-img{filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,#grayscale");/* Firefox 10+ /filter: gray;/ IE6-9 /-webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);/ Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ /-webkit-transition: all .6s ease;/ Fade to color for Chrome and Safari /-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; / Fix for transition flickering */-moz-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}`

.portfolio-img:hover{filter:none;-webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);-moz-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);-o-transition:.8s;-ms-transition:.8s;-moz-transition:.8s;-webkit-transition:.8s;transition:.8s}

Comment: He's referring to the "hover" effect ... when you hover over a gray-scale image, it gradually starts to gain color.

Comment: Thanks guys, and thanks for the chart NullPointer.  Much appreciated. I really want to use this gray to color hover and I just can't find a great solution.  There are flaws with 100% I have found. Do one of you know of a solution that can work in all CURRENT browsers?

Comment: Also, why would FF not support the ease effect?

Comment: @Matt the solution [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because the **IE** and up to **Firefox** version 16 does not supports filters

from the source http://caniuse.com/css-filters

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I view this effect in the latest FF, the shadow effect eases but the actual photo does not. What are your thoughts on that? Could it just not support the ease?

Comment: @Matt check the link ,,,:-) i have commented  question --) will get you solution

Comment: @Matt or direct demo http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11137205/grayscale.html works fine in firefox and ie checked ...rather by me now

Comment: Thank you for the solid info!

Comment: had another issue but I forgot to post. To separate out the issue for the sake of SO users I started another question. DO you mind viewing? If so, thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304218/grayscale-hover-effect-slow-in-ff-fast-in-chrome-ie-and-others

Comment: I wanted to work on this before changing over the grayscale hover effect.