# Grayscale hover effect slow in FF, fast in Chrome, IE and others

Tags: css, hover

Not sure what is going on.  The hover effect on the page below is very slow to respond in Firefox. When you scroll, the page is not smooth either. This particular page runs smoothly in other current browsers. The site is very fast so I am not sure what to think.

http://thebc.co/our-work

Comment: Tried it with latest FF on Win7, no lag.

Comment: @Keaukraine Thanks for checking it. So the effect isnt slow on FF for you?  Also, in Chrome (on this same page) the page jerks a little when you scroll.Can you try this in Chrome? Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm at home now, on Ubuntu 12.04. Latest FF, latest Chromium. Everything is normal and smooth.

Comment: Much appreciated keaukraine!

Comment: Anyone else want to help with different specs?