# how to greyout an image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I need to grey out disabled images in the asp page but I dont know how to achieve that

my current code is given below

```
<ul class="flag">
                <li>
                    <img src="flag-china.png" alt="china" onclick="setLanguage('Chinese');"   style="cursor:pointer"/></li>
                <li>
                    <img src="flag-france.png" alt="france" onclick="setLanguage('French');" style="cursor:pointer" /></li>

                    <img src="us.png" alt="us" onclick="setLanguage('English');" style="cursor:pointer" /></li>
            </ul>
```

I need to disable and grey out every flag except the last one

Comment: Try this: [Convert img to grayscale HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css) but you could probably make a grayscale version of the images yourself and reference them accordingly, if they are only those 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found following code sample [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale). Call the gray out version when you need.

```
public static Bitmap MakeGrayscale3(Bitmap original)
{
   //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
   Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

   //get a graphics object from the new image
   Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

   //create the grayscale ColorMatrix
   ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
      new float[][] 
      {
         new float[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
         new float[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
         new float[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
         new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
      });

   //create some image attributes
   ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

   //set the color matrix attribute
   attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

   //draw the original image on the new image
   //using the grayscale color matrix
   g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
      0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

   //dispose the Graphics object
   g.Dispose();
   return newBitmap;
}
```