# Images to turn from grayscale to color one by one

Tags: jquery, image, colors, loader, grayscale

I have 5 images placed in a div, the images are color but I want them to all be grayscaled firstly and then the first 3 to slowly fade into color one by one after the page loads. I've tried to achieve this using various jquery scripts like jQuery grayscale, desaturate, etc. to no success. Can someone please figure it out for me?

Script looks like this:

```
<div class="cupImg">
   <img src="img/cup.png" alt="" /><img src="img/cup.png" alt="" /><img src="img/cup.png" alt="" /><img src="img/cup.png" alt="" /><img src="img/cup.png" class="last" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Show your jquery code.

Comment: I don't have any at the moment, as I tried a few plugins but those aren't working for my particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set all images to grayscale with .gray class in CSS3

`https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028908/2630208`

2. Set transition animation to your  elements with CSS3
3. Use .slice(0,3) jQuery method to select first three elements from your
4. Remove .gray class with pure jQuery

`http://jsfiddle.net/8Q39r/1/`

BTW. Code won't work in Presto's based Opera. It's a feature limitation of that browser.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working temporarily using a hide and show but this is perfect.