# Convert svg to grayscale using php

Tags: php, pdf, svg

I'm using tcpdf to generate a pdf file, and have to conditionally convert coloured SVG files to grayscale.

But i'm not able to find any useful libraries to do that.

Is it even possible?

**PS!** I dont have imagemagick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

Comment: @RobertLongson No, i can't use HTML/CSS

Comment: Then this is off topic as it's a tool/library request.

Comment: @Kristian: Hi, did you find the solution for this?