# How do I desaturate and saturate an image using CSS?

Tags: html, image, css, grayscale

**Update**

I just realized that the desaturation is only working in Chrome. How do I make it work in FF, IE and other browsers? (Headline changed)

---

I'm converting a color picture to greyscale by following the suggestions here:  [Convert an image to grayscale in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css)

And it works great (in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/7mNEC/

```
<img src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/350x496q90/822/z7ds.jpg" />

// CSSS
img {
    filter:         url(~"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:    grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:     grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter:      grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; 
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But I'm not able to remove the desaturation on e.g. mouse over.

Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just have to reverse the grayscale for each browser prefix CSS property:

```
img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter:    grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter:     grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter:      grayscale(0%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mNEC/1/

Comment: Great, that worked. But do you see why desaturation doesn't work in FF and IE?

Comment: @Steven It looks like [Firefox doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Gecko_notes) the full `filter` spec yet because it hasn't solidified enough. IE 9 deprecated `-ms-filter` and IE 10 doesn't support it.

Comment: Well, the picture is disagreeable but the tip is pretty useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Since this question is about *saturation*, the [`saturate()` filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#saturate()_2) may be a better fit. This also allows for super-saturated colors (values above 100%):

```
img {
    filter: saturate(0%);
}
img:hover {
    filter: saturate(300%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1jeh8aL/

Comment: You're jsfiddle is broken.

Comment: @N-ate Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 9):

Its cooler if you add a transition like this:

```
  img {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter:    grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter:     grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter:      grayscale(100%);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
  }
  img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter:    grayscale(0%);
    -ms-filter:     grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter:      grayscale(0%);
  }
```