# div and span css styles for form buttons

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, html

I used the SO questions [Gray out image with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286275/gray-out-image-with-css) and
[Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css) to construct a css wrapper that would grey out a button, and also prevent clicks to it. I tried first in a separate css file, but this example uses inline css styles and gives the same result. Here are 4 buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <span style="opacity:0.4; pointer-events: none;">
            <input type='submit' value='Span Inside' />
        </span>
    </form>

    <form>
        <div  style="opacity:0.4; pointer-events: none;">
            <input type='submit' value='Div Inside' />
        </div>
    </form>

    <div  style="opacity:0.4; pointer-events: none;">
        <form>
            <input type='submit' value='Div Outside' />
        </form>
    </div>

    <span style="opacity:0.4; pointer-events: none;">
        <form>
            <input type='submit' value='Span Outside' />
        </form>
    </span>

</body>
</html>
```

All four buttons in this example do not respond to clicks in any of Firefox 15.0.1, Safari 6.0 or Chrome 21.0.1180.89, which is what I expected.

In Firefox, all 4 buttons are greyed out, opacity 0.4, which is what I expected.

In Safari and Chrome, the first 3 buttons are greyed out, but the 4th button, with the span elements outside the form elements, has opacity 1.0.

Is there a bug in the browsers, or is it in in my understanding, please?

Comment: span allows only phrasing context inside it. It should not allow a nested form element and, as you can see, every browser may behaves differently

Comment: The markup is non-conformant so you should not be surprised when browsers coerce your markup into a less invalid form. For instance, very old versions of Firefox used to do this too.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. So, if I want to wrap a style around arbitrary content and have it not insert newlines, I should write <div style="opacity:0.4; pointer-events: none; display:inline-block; >content</div> ?

Answer (score 1):

If your tryig to disable an input field or button on a form then you should be using [the `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: Yes, but the form in the middle is actually created by a function I cannot modify, and presented to me as a string. I could text-process the string, but that's somewhat unpredictable. So I wrap the form in a style instead.

Comment: You can programmatically set the disabled attribute via javscript after your form has been appended to the DOM.