# Firefox grayscale wokrs only on local

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, grayscale

this is my css:

```
.categorys img
{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 8px;
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray; /* For IE 6 - 9 */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;
}

.categorys img:hover
{
    filter: none;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

It works fine when i run it on local. but when i upload it to the server (on the web), the grayscale images on firefox are invisible.

btw, on hover it removes the grayscale effect and the images are visible

i have tried to use this code:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

when i use that, grayscale works fine on firefox, but then it doesnt work on internet explorer (images always have normal colors).

anyone is familiar with that issue?

Comment: I guess this type of question is already asked in this forum. you should check this link. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter`

Comment: Im using IE9, its not the same issue :/

Comment: did you try this?
`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";
  
 filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";`

I've checked it with IE Tester tool and I can see the image in gray color..

Comment: The thing with IE is that it stops working when i apply the filter url i mentioned on my post, but without thta filter FF wont work, tried also: `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";
  
 filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)";`

Comment: Hi Guy,

Check this URL. using a little bit jquery you can get a nice effect.

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/jQuery-Color-Fade-Hover-Effect/75983