# How to make grayscale and transition effect working in firefox and ie?

Tags: css

To make work grayscale work in IE 10 and IE 11 I could do what I found in this question: [internet explorer 10 - howto apply grayscale filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter), but that is for single image. I need to do it for all images. How could I do that?

```
//.bc contain all the images
.bc {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix%20type='matrix'%20values='0.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200.3333%200.3333%200.3333%200%200%200%200%200%201%200'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(.9); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */

    filter: grayscale(90%);

    transition : filter 500ms linear;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 500ms linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-filter 500ms linear;
}
```

So, how can I make it work on multiple images? And how can I make the transition effect work (it is still not working in Firefox)?

Comment: please note for mozilla browser the transition effect only not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-moz-filter`:

```
.bc {
    filter: grayscale(90%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(90%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
}
```

Comment: Nope. For mozilla it works with svg but the problem with moz is transition effect only.

Comment: `moz-filter` doesn't do anything interesting. How did this get +1?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) from Lea Verou  look it up [here](http://cdnjs.com/)

```
.bc {
        filter: grayscale(90%);
    }
```

or use the standard

```
  .bc {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%);
        -moz-filter: grayscale(90%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(90%);
        filter: grayscale(90%);
    }
```