# Grayscale CSS Background in internet explorer 10 and 11?

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Grayscale is working fine with all the browsers except ie10 and ie11.
I have even tried [this](https://github.com/kununu-labs/gray). It worked well with images these are embedded in HTML code, but is not working as background image, declared in CSS.

I have even tried:

```
 img.grayscale:hover {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
}

svg {
    background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-IzPWLqY4gJ0/T01CPzNb1KI/AAAAAAAACgA/_8uyj68QhFE/s400/a2cf7051-5952-4b39-aca3-4481976cb242.jpg);
}
```

This does not work either.

The CSS code that I use to grayscale the background image:

```
#callouts{
min-height: 219px;
margin: 33px 0px 0px 0px;
padding-left: 40px;

background: url("/static/images/images/gs-pricing-4panel.png") no-repeat;

filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); 

filter: gray;

-webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter

Answer (score 1):

I've used this tool any time I needed a gradient:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: i have tried that also but i want to grayscale the background image only. I dont want to use linear gradient

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't yet support the CSS filter property, either as built-in filter functions or as a url referencing an SVG filter.  The only way to get a filter effect working is to use inline SVG for your image, and apply an SVG filter to that.

Also, IE doesn't like data:URIs expressed in plain text, they need to be either fully URL-encoded or base-64 encoded.  But it wouldn't make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of the jQuery plugin at https://github.com/karlhorky/gray. Background images are supported. Your element with the background image needs the class `grayscale`. [Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ur1AmXelJJh2X73pb8eo?p=preview).

```
<div class="grayscale" id="callouts"></div>
```

**OR:** If you don't want to use the `grayscale` class name, you can manually invoke the jQuery plugin on your element with JavaScript. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tZ4JNmfmsbFVUmu2SEGK?p=preview).

```
$('#callouts').gray();
```

Answer (score 0):

try JS fix

It is using javascript to detect the browser and creates a canvas and then uses filter

http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/