# grayscale an image on hover in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have gotten this to work everywhere but IE 10.

**Nothing seems to work.**

This was an elegant solution and it worked everywhere.. **except** IE 10.

```
.list-items li:hover img {
/*  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); 
    filter: gray; */
    /*-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); */
/*    background-blend-mode: luminosity;
*/
}
```

So, then I went and downloaded this jQuery plugin '[Gray](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray)'.

Basically your supposed to be able to easily `toggleClass` "grayscale" on any images you want to be gray -- and it actually works in IE when you manually add class grayscale inline with the img. *ie.* `<img src="/images/imstarving.jpg" class="grayscale">`

But I **cannot get this to work on hover in IE 10.** Again, everywhere else works; but not IE 10.

**Js code :**

```
$("img").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("grayscale");
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("grayscale");
    }
);
```

I have tried many things like the above to either `addClass` / `removeClass` or `toggleClass` and guess what **still doesn't work in IE 10!!**

Any pointers?

*Update: I had to use an image swap :( due to time restraints (normal image > grayscale image). But would love to see a solution to this if anyone has one.*

Comment: Try: `$(this).gray();`

Comment: Huh? In what context?

Comment: put the code where you add the class

Comment: Yeah didn't work.Thanks though. I guess I have to cut out gray images and do a old school hover image swap. Ridiculous!!

Comment: try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter

Comment: it doesn't work on hover though for some reason

Comment: this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KatieK/qhU7d/2/ does not work in ie10?

Comment: Your JavaScript is fine - it's the CSS `filter` that was discontinued after IE9. This solution worked best for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21741216/4952851

Comment: That question does not gray on hover but does the opposite