# Is it possible to filter an image in IE8 to black and white?

Tags: html, css

I've tried the next code but it doesn't work even in IE10:

```css
img#lena-desaturate{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(#greyscale);
  filter: gray;
}
```

Or an example [here](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/DcBIH).

Comment: Please include your HTML (the SVG-part of it at least). Could you tell us if the code works in other browsers besides IE? Or is it jammed everywhere?

Comment: Read the question carrefully please. I have a link to an example on it. Works in all browsers besides IE(tested on IE10, IE9, IE8)

Comment: I've read it, and checked the example as well. I must confirm, have you done the SVG-part as well, or just trying to create this effect with CSS only?

Comment: I'm trying to do this with only CSS. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grayscale filter has been natively supported by Internet Explorer since version 6, but recently Microsoft decided to remove this native CSS filter and since version 10, IE does not display grayscale images using the old technique.

But there is a cross-browser Grayscale image solution

Read this article  - http://www.majas-lapu-izstrade.lv/cross-browser-grayscale-image-example-using-css3-js/

Comment: You should mention that this solution requires the use of JS as well.

Comment: Yes, my question was about CSS only. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Read this answers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the effect working in some browsers and some of their versions in plain CSS, but it is recommended by several sources that adding the SVG option will increase the browser support.

[**See this example.**](http://thenewcode.com/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS)

There is also a separate IE-fix promised to work in versions 6 - 9, which goes for CSS but is **still referring to the use of SVG**:

```
img.desaturate{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Read the whole article and you will see that is mentioned that it will not work on IE. It's all on the red band.

Comment: Sure it wont work if you're not using the SVG which it requires. There just seems to be no widely supported pure-CSS solution for this. Either it is SVG or JS supported, and in this case I would rather go for SVG.