# Make a grayscale image with css in IE11 running in Quirks mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I need to convert some colorful images on an internal legacy web application to grayscale. I figured the easiest way would be to use CSS filters. The users of this application access it via IE11 due to a Group Policy. This application must also be run using Quirks (IE5) document mode, otherwise crazy things happen (rendering issues, javascript not working, etc).

I have tried the following code (as well as code from [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grayscale-image-web/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813142/internet-explorer-10-howto-apply-grayscale-filter), and [here](http://thenewcode.com/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS))

```
img.desaturate {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
}
```

with no effect. Given this criteria (IE11 running with IE5 Document mode), is there anything I can do to get these grayscale images, and if so, how?

*note: redesigning the application to work with more modern technologies is not currently funded, and will not be in the future.*

*note: converting each image to grayscale with some script and saving the output is also not an option, as there are millions of images available.*

Link to example that shows colorful Google logo: https://jsfiddle.net/bq2mw5ya/2/

Comment: Can you perhaps post a Plunker or other code sample?  If there's nothing wrong with your CSS, then maybe there's something wrong with your HTML :)

Comment: if filter:gray; is **set last** & IE using IE5 (quirks mode), it works if activex are allowed to run, else nothing happens test http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyYmEw on bottom right, click export, select zip and then run file on local with same config as your site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually i turn my comment as an answer for feed back:

IE specific filter should stand last, so it is not overide by a next one.

**Activex should also allowed to run**

and of course, it should be in quirk mode ...

```
img.desaturate {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url(desaturate.svg#greyscale);
    filter: gray;
}
```

Comment: Looks like all I needed was the last line, as this application doesn't support anything but IE11+IE5 anyways. Thanks for the info.

Comment: what about IE11 not in quirks-mode?